# Remove some junk characters from server console log

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5

Please look in to the picture,here am trying to open(with vi editor) my server console log file(around 100MB) and it takes more than two minutes to open with so many special characters.after deleting the first line (means typing "dd")then i can easily view the file and size of the file is also reduced very much.My server OS is RHEL 5.4 and jboss is running in to it.

Please help me to avoid such junk characters coming to my server console log files and it helps me to save my valuable space in server.

[image]

Comment: What console log are we talking about?

Comment: Those are nulls. Any idea what's writing them to your log? That's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest way would be filter non-printable chars, like that

```
cat console.log |perl -pe 's/[^[:print:]\n]//gi' > cleared_log.file
```

or just

```
perl -pe 's/[^[:print:]\n]//gi' console.log
```

But best way would be to figure out why u have such a junk in that log file

Answer (score 0):

In VI, a ^@ represents a NULL (ASCII value 0) character. Googling for appears to suggest this is a known issue with JBoss and Logrotate. Check this website for some insight and a suggested fix:

http://efreedom.com/Question/2-71341/JBoss-Logrotate-Create-Log-Files-Full-NUL-Characters